# Dynamic Cache Loading in Service Worker

Tags: javascript, caching, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Good day StackOverflow!

i got a concern regarding my sw. when opening the page. I dont know how to explain this using technical terms so i will just explain thin based on my observation.

When i open a new home page, it loads the page and saves the cache. when i login to the website, the page changes as it should, generating the image, username, etc. So far so good. When i logout, my expected page should be the default homepage but it still displaying the page like when a user log in to the site.

this happens on my local server, remote pc, and smart phones(both on web page and PWA app)

If i delete the generated cache, it returns to normal. What should I do in this situation?

here is my sw.js file:

```
const dynamicCacheName = 'ver-v1';
// activate event
self.addEventListener('activate', evt => {
  evt.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(keys => {
      return Promise.all(keys
        .filter(key => key !== dynamicCacheName)
        .map(key => caches.delete(key))
      );
    })
  );
});
// fetch event
self.addEventListener('fetch', evt => {
  evt.respondWith(
    caches.match(evt.request).then(cacheRes => {
      return cacheRes || fetch(evt.request).then(fetchRes => {
        return caches.open(dynamicCacheName).then(cache => {
          cache.put(evt.request.url, fetchRes.clone());
          return fetchRes;
        })
      });
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: I think that when i logout, the cache still thinks that I am still logged in to the application, thus it still displaying the login page. how should I deal with this?

Comment: The problem is that `cache.put(...)` is most likely saving the API responses for the user (i.e. you should exclude the api calls from your cache, this also raises issues with new data from your API since the old data is still cached)

Comment: actually the cache.put(...) is the line of code that saves all the cache. if i comment this one, PWA offline will not work

Comment: i will try to work with this and see if i can just delete the API on cache only when i click logout..

Comment: I didn't mean to completely remove the `cache.put` but rather to place it inside of an if statement

Answer (score 0):

You are caching the authenticated page. You need to capture when the user logs out and clear the cached page and fetch the unauthenticated version.

There are many, more complex ways to handle this scenario, but I have a feel a bit beyond where you are right now.

Just a hint. You can render and cache responses in your service worker. You can catch requests and serve different versions based on the request before they are sent to the network. For example, you can check to see if the Bearer token is in your request header. If so and it is current/valid then you serve the cached authenticated version, if not then the public version.

I do all sorts of things like this and more in my applications. Service worker is a fantastic tool, but it requires thinking differently than we did in the past and sometimes those concepts are difficult to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

Good day. I used Workbox and now got it to work, but cache is too big to use.

This is what i did:

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.4.1/workbox-sw.js');

if (workbox) {
  const CACHE_PREFIX = 'v01';

  workbox.setConfig({
    clientsClaim: true,
    debug: true,
    skipWaiting: true
  });
  workbox.core.setLogLevel(workbox.core.LOG_LEVELS.warn);

  // Javascript and CSS rule
  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new RegExp('^.*(?:js|css)'),
    new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst(
      { cacheName: `${CACHE_PREFIX}-asset` }
    ),
  );

  // Main rule
  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new RegExp('^.*(?:)'),
    new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst(
      { cacheName: `${CACHE_PREFIX}-main` }
    ),
  );

} else {
  console.log(`Boo! Workbox didn't load `);
}
```